# Failed to start MySQL Database XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to run mysql database server on xampp but the status doesn't change . I've tried all the solutions that i found on the internet but it didn't solve my problem .
Any recommendations ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If mysql is not starting in xampp, it might be a port conflict issue. Mysql run by default on port 3306. you need to check if another application is occupying that port.
use following command to check app occupying a port

```
Linux: netstat -tulpn
Window: netstat -a -b
```

if you find an application occupying that port, stop the application and restart xampp.
As an alternative, you can go to php.ini file or click configure in the dropdown shown in the image and change the mysql port to 3307

Comment: Hi , i changed the port to 3307 but it still doesn't work . What should i do ?

Comment: The most important thing is to identify the service or application occupying port 3306, then stop the app or service and restart xampp. that's is the most guarantee solution